# Exception com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: android

Hi I am working on demo app where I am facing below issue when I am trying to run app.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.xyz.firstfirebasedemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // enabling multidex support
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


}
```

[image]

Comment: add complete logcat

Comment: @deepakjohn141 see updated question

Comment: try  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.2', keep verison number same as buildtoolsversion

Comment: try adding com.google.gms to exlude group also

Comment: @deepakjohn141 how to add multiple libs in a group, I already have `com.android.support`

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/multiple-excludes-for-multiple-dependencies/11573/6 gothrough this

Comment: @deepakjohn141 `all*.exclude group: 'com.google.gms', module: 'support-v4'
` is this correct ?